# Single multi-line equation with comments on rows

Tags: equations, align

I can't find a way to write a multi-line equation, which I would later refer to as on single equation, and write comments on some of rows.

The thing I want is pretty much like here:

[Multi-row text comment in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256774/multi-row-text-comment-in-align-environment)

and here:

[Show equation number only once in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17528/show-equation-number-only-once-in-align-environment)

Is it possible to combine these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `align`, you may use `aligned` within an `equation` environment.

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{my eq}
\begin{aligned}
  a&=b+c &&\text{note 1} \\
  &=d+e+f&&\text{note 2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I wrote \eqref{my eq}.
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]